# Only samsung mobile is not getting notification from fcm

Tags: php, android, google-cloud-messaging

I am getting notification to all android device except samsung mobile.
This problem started after I updated url from "https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send" to
"https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send" because gcm suddenly stopped sending notification to all devices..
After updating url,notification is not going to samsung devices
I am not getting wheee is the problem.Please help me with solution
Thank you
here is my fcm code in php

```
$msg = array(
    'message' => json_encode($parsedMsg),
    'title' => '',
    'subtitle' => '',
    'tickerText' => '',
    'vibrate' => 1,
    'sound' => 1,
    'largeIcon' => 'large_icon',
    'smallIcon' => 'small_icon'
);


if(count($registrationIds) == 0){
    return json_encode(array('success' => 0, 'failure'=>0));
}


$fields = array(
    'registration_ids' => $registrationIds,
    'data' => $msg
);

$headers = array(
    'Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY,
    'Content-Type: application/json'
);

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

return $result;
```

}

Comment: if other phone gets notification , this issue is not with your server side code i guess. 

do you have other samsung phone ? check other phones, also check firebase console dashboard, there should be some log regarding any issue

Comment: Yes,I checked with other samsung devices also but I am not getting notification.

Comment: Sometime fcm pending in some device like samsung cause the battery optimal. so fcm not always real time. (in my case)

Comment: Are you getting any error/response message?

Comment: @quintin I am not getting any error.

Comment: if the problem is still there, whats it the version of your samsung device. Please edit your onMessageReceived()